# Make submit application check on the client side first

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

When you "Apply" for a job you are taken to a page where Stack Overflow mentions your developer story will be submitted if no résumé is attached.  There is a section on the bottom that says "Introduce Yourself".  If you click the **Submit** button without entering an introduction the form posts and you get a hard refresh.

Can this be changed to client side validation AND server side validation rather than just server side validation?

Maybe we should also look into using the same format where the Submit button by default is not enabled (disabled state) and doesn't become enabled unless you type something in the "Introduce Yourself" text box.  Don't forget if you go this route to handle copy paste and copy cut such that the button is disabled / enabled on this as well (sorry many sites forget about this!).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your feedback.

At some point, we're going to be working on this part of the application process anyway due to a forthcoming feature on the employer side.  I don't have a timetable for when that will happen.  When it does, however, we're probably going to look at making the application process friendlier still, which includes revisiting how validation is done.

I do know this project isn't the very next thing on our list, so [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) it is.  It's a good suggestion, though — we don't do a lot of client-side validation anywhere on the site, and adding some (correctly) can help the user experience.